# "Where does he go?" vs. "Where does he go to?"

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between "Where does he go?" and "Where does he go to?"
Are there any hidden connotations in adding "to"?

If I needed to come up with a question for "Max goes to the library twice a week", which one of the two options I would have to use?

> Where does Max go to twice a week?

or

> Where does Max go twice a week?

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of "to" implies a definite destination for going: to school, to New York...

Without "to", the location is not specific: shopping, walking...

> Twice a week, Max **goes to** the gym.

vs:

> Twice a week, Max **goes** shopping.

---

If you know that Max is going to a specific place place, you can use "to". However, usually you know nothing about his whereabouts (otherwise you would not be asking), therefore you should use the more generic form, without "to".

The good thing is that the answer does not need to follow the rule of the question in this case. The answer will you "to" independent of the question.

> Where does he **go**? *(no "to")*
>
> He **goes to** the library. *("to")*

or:

> Where does he **go to**? *("to")*
>
> He **goes** for a walk. *(no "to"; the understanding is that he does not go to a specific place, unlike the question implied)*